# Finding First Integrals in the case $2xy u_x - (x^2+y^2) u_y =0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Good day,

As described in the title, I want to find two First Integrals (FI) to the PDE $$2xy u_x - (x^2+y^2) u_y =0$$

Of course, $u$ is a FI and the solution of the PDE ist $u(x,y)=u_0$. But I want to find the other FI. I can't find it.
Here: $x'=2xy$ and $y'=-x^2-y^2$

An easy example: If we have $x'=y, y'=-x$ then $x^2+y^2$ would be a FI since $\frac{d}{dt} (x^2+y^2)=2xx'+2yy'=0$.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: $(x^2+y^2)\,dx+2xy\,dy=d(x^3/3+xy^2)$, so $x^3/3+xy^2$ is your integral (if I didn't make a mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $dy/dx = y'/x' = 1/2(-x/y-y/x)$. Define $x/y = z$, then $y=x/z$, $dy/dx = (z-xdz/dx)/z^2$ so we have the ODE: $(z-xdz/dx) = z^2/2(-z-1/z) = 1/2(-z^3-z)$

$$ dz/dx x = 3/2 z+1/2 z^3$$

From there you get: $$dz/(3/2z +1/2 z^3) = dx/x$$

which you can integrate and solve.